# Deploy Server Side Rendering and Client Side Rendering angular 10 applications in same project

Tags: angular, apache, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular10

We have the server-side rendering and client-side rendering applications in the same angular 10 project.

[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) should load the server-side rendering application.
[www.domain.com/admin](http://www.domain.com/admin) should load a client-side rendering application.

Is there any method to deploy SSR and CSR in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same idea with you. In my opinion:

```
1- dist-server (SSR) you will put all in root dir www
2- dist (CSR) you will put all in sub-folder naming admin
```

And we will have 2 apps with 2  index.html